# How I can deploy a subfolder into my bucket's root path?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

For my react App I use the following `buildspec.yml` to deploy a reast Single Page Application:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - npm run build

cache:
  paths:
    - /root/.npm/**/*

artifacts:
  files:
    - ./build/**
```

I also created an s3 bucket as static website and I deploy it directly via codeploy. But the folder that is deployed is into the `./build` istead of the bucket's root. Is there a way to translate the paths of the codebuild's output artifacts into the deployed paths?

The codebuild path is used  as a step in a codepipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do that you must specify a `base-directory` then tell the codebuild to set everything as artifact. This would be your final `buildspec.yml`:

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - npm install
  build:
    commands:
      - npm run build

cache:
  paths:
    - /root/.npm/**/*

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  base-directory: './build'
```

And you also can safely delete the rogue `./build` folder into your s3 bucket.